# How to use QSqlTableModel along with QTreeView

Tags: pyqt, qtreeview, qsqlquery, qsqltablemodel, qsqldatabase

I am using sqlite database (webscrap.db). I want to make the model to display the data in the field "name" of the database table "userin". How can i fetch data using QSqlTableModel and display it with QTreeView ?

Answer (score 0):

It can be solved by creating a database connection and make a QtSqlTableModel.Then set model for treeview.

```
db = QtSql.QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QSQLITE')
db.setDatabaseName('databasename.db')
model = QtSql.QSqlTableModel()
model.setTable('tablename')
model.setEditStrategy(QtSql.QSqlTableModel.OnManualSubmit)
model.select() 
treeview.setModel(model)
```